# cassandra 3.9 flush fails

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We have a 5 node cassandra cluster running cassandra 3.9. We have a keyspace "ks" and a table "cf". We created several indexes on the table like "cf_c1_idx", "cf_c1_idx_1", "cf_c2_idx".
When I do a nodetool flush, the flush of 1 of the index files fails with the following exception:

```
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.RuntimeException: Last written key DecoratedKey(4dd1d75b-e52f-6c49-e7cd-c52a968e70de, 4dd1d75be52f6c49e7cdc52a968e70de) >= current key DecoratedKey(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, 5331cc31ae396031e6be66312c89c379) writing into /var/lib/cassandra/data/ks/cf-8d8b1ba0081c11e7a4206f8b05d669ae/.cf_c1_idx_1/mc-401-big-Data.db
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.beforeAppend(BigTableWriter.java:122)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.append(BigTableWriter.java:161)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SimpleSSTableMultiWriter.append(SimpleSSTableMultiWriter.java:48)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.writeSortedContents(Memtable.java:458)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.call(Memtable.java:493)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.call(Memtable.java:380)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I run nodetool flush again after a few seconds, it succeeds without a hitch. We also notice the same exception showing up during commitlog replay after restarting a node sometimes. We end up deleting the commitlog directory so cassandra can start and run a repair to sync the data that was lost. Is this happening because of secondary indexes not getting updated in time? Also, this is a read intensive cluster.

Comment: Can you show the table and index DDL? Also why do you have to create multiple secondary indexes?